# Can't boot with new RAM on gigabyte X299 UD4 (rev. 1.0)

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, motherboard, bios

My pc currently works with a single 8GB RAM GB, I recently bought a new RAM memory exactly the same as I already have.

When I installed the dual channel windows crashes after a stressful use. I did some tests with software and apparently the new RAM has problems, after knowing this I tried to use only the new RAM in the slot that was the previous one but the BIOS not booting (RAM issue). I restarted the bios and the CMOS but it didn't work either. I tried the new RAM on another computer and it worked, I don't know what to do to make it work on my PC.

**Motherboard**:

```
Motherboard Intel X299 Durable motherboard con RGB Fusion, Digital LED, Dual M.2, 120dB SNR ALC1220, Intel Gaming LAN, USB 3.1 gen 2 Tipo-A
```

**New Memory Ram**:

```
xpg gammix d10 8gb 3000mhz ddr4 Model: AX4U300038G16-SBG
```

Comment: Kingston & Crucial have online databases to check the RAM requirements, e.g. https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory-buying-guide . If the RAM meets their guidelines and doesn't work, return it.

Comment: The RAM is the same that the one that works, that is the weird thing.